# How I can show and add items to Sharepoint List via Powershell?

Tags: list, powershell, sharepoint-2010, intranet, powershell-remoting

hi I want to show and add items in Sharepoint via Powershell (I use for testing a list and a libary)

The name is Powershell-Test

the Url is

```
http//intranet/departments/it/abt/Lists/Powershell-Test/AllItems.aspx
```

I enable remote on the Sharepoint Server and make a remote connection to this from my localhost.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName [sharepoint server] -Authentication Negotiate -Credential [Domain\name]

if((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
}

$webURL = "http//intranet/departments/it/abt/Lists/"
$listname = "Powershell-Test"

$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL

$web.lists | format-table title 

$list = $web.LIsts[$listName]

$list.items | foreach { $_[„Title“] + „`n“ + $_[„Body“] }
```

The Problem is that I don#t get the connection to the list :(

How I can to this?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have permission to access the site.

I also presume you don't have a site or subsite with the name "Lists".

I don't think you can use Get-SPWeb with the path "/Lists/" within it (unless the site was named "lists").

Could you try:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell 
}

$siteURL = "http//intranet/departments/it/abt/"
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteURL
$list = $web.Lists["Powershell-Test"]
$list.Items | foreach { $_["Title"] + "`n" + $_["Body"] }
```